# Google maps visual refresh text and lines are blurry

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Comparing what is on google maps with the version of google maps with the api (with the visual refresh). The text is a bit larger on the API version, it also has this text shadow and a slight blur.

Is there a way to alter the css of it or something to make it sharper/change the font of the text in the API version to make it more visually appealing? (Alter the font before its drawn on the canvas?)

Is there a way to know what the css classes are to alter?

**Maps API Version (with Visual Refresh)**

[image: API Version - Blurry]

**Version on Google Maps**

[image: Google maps]

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the saturation can help. You can customize the appearance of your map using the styled maps feature.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling